# Does the refresh_token request must come from the same URI origin as in the original redirect_uri?

Tags: google-oauth

I've been playing around with Oauth 2.0 Playground to understand Google's Oauth implementation and Oauth in general:

https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground

And, I had an idea.  I generated an access token running under user_A.  Then, I took that access token, and used it in in Postman to one of the approved scopes API, and it ran fine.  Since it worked, I figured I could use it in my Apps Script without doing all the other Oauth plumbing / boilerplate junk.  And, it worked fine there too:

```
var token = 'the generated access token from Oauth 2.0 playground' ;
var refresh_token1 = 'the generated refresh token' ; 
var client_id = 'the client ID from Oauth 2.0 Client ID in Google Cloud';
var client_secret = 'the client secret from Oauth 2.0 Client ID in Google Cloud';
var api_endpoint = 'the REST endpoint to test (simple GET call)' ;

function myFunction() {
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(api_endpoint, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
    }
  });
  var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  
    Logger.log(result);
}
```

Running myFunction() in Apps Script console produces the expected response as shown in the execution log.  So, then I wondered, would this also work for the refresh token:

```
function refresh_access_token() {
    
    var options = {};
    options.method = 'post' ;
    options.contentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' ;
    options.client_secret = client_secret ;
    options.grant_type = 'refresh_token';
    options.refresh_token = refresh_token1 ;    
    options.client_id = client_id ;
   
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', options);

    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

    Logger.log(result);
}
```

But, when I run refresh_access_token(), I get the generic "invalid_grant" error.  I used the request / response in Oauth 2.0 Playground to craft the options body for URLFetchApp.fetch, so I'm fairly certain that's ok.  My thoughts are that the access_token is checked against the original redirect_uri.  I suppose that makes sense from a security perspective, because if you somehow hijack or steal the refresh token, you could just keep generating access tokens anywhere from any client, including cURL.  Thoughts?

Comment: I did realize that along with the stolen refresh token, the attacker would need the client id and client secret.  So, I suppose there's an added layer of security there.